# Alignment and performance

Tags: c++, c, linux, sse, libc

Routines `strcmp` for comparing `char *` and `memcmp` for everything else, do they run faster on memory block (on x86_64) which is somehow aligned (how?)? Does libc use `SSE` for this routines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends, but on architectures where alignment matters or where SIMD instructions are available, typically the routines will operate on leading bytes, then do as many wide aligned operations as the data allows, then operate on trailing bytes.

Whether the leading and trailing bytes are contributing significantly to the processing time for your data can be determined by experiment.

Comment: Would this approach work in the case of strcmp? If the two strings are misaligned by a different (mod 16) value, the 'leading part' of each string will be of a different length. So, you can't start comparing the strings from that point onwards, since you are at different positions in the two strings.

Comment: Indeed, it won't work for any case where the alignment of input and output differ, but for most cases the start of data is aligned to the size of the largest data type in the system ( on common OSes). You then have to ask whether your particular use case of comparing or copying something offset from the start of your data means you want to try aligning that address, or using some other technique.

Answer (score 0):

If you worry about performance for comparison, you should take a look at well-known [Boyer-Moore alogrithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) and [this post](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html) from GNU Grep author, Mike Haertel.

He explains how one can manage to be really fast about searching something in a data block.

His summary is quite clear about what to do :

> - Use Boyer-Moore (and unroll its inner loop a few times).
> - Roll your own unbuffered input using raw system calls.  Avoid copying
>     the input bytes before searching them.  (Do, however, use buffered
>     *output*.  The normal grep scenario is that the amount of output is
>     small compared to the amount of input, so the overhead of output
>     buffer copying is small, while savings due to avoiding many small
>     unbuffered writes can be large.)
> - Don't look for newlines in the input until after you've found a match.
> - Try to set things up (page-aligned buffers, page-sized read chunks,
>     optionally use mmap) so the kernel can ALSO avoid copying the bytes.